# How do I detect any of 4 characters in a string and then return their index?

Tags: python

I would understand how to do this assuming that I was only looking for one specific character, but in this instance I am looking for any of the 4 operators, '+', '-', '*', '/'. The function returns -1 if there is no operator in the passed string, txt, otherwise it returns the position of the leftmost operator. So I'm thinking find() would be optimal here.

What I have so far:

```
def findNextOpr(txt):
# txt must be a nonempty string.
    if len(txt) <= 0 or not isinstance(txt, str):
        print("type error: findNextOpr")
        return "type error: findNextOpr"
    if '+' in txt:
        return txt.find('+')
    elif '-' in txt:
        return txt.find('-')
    else
        return -1
```

I think if I did what I did for the '+' and '-' operators for the other operators, it wouldn't work for multiple instances of that operator in one expression. Can a loop be incorporated here?

Comment: If you're trying to implement a calculator, look into the Shunting Yard algorithm

Comment: In a string like `2 - 3 + 4`, your description says you want the index of that `-`, but your code will return the index of that `+`. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach is not very efficient, as you will iterate over `txt`, multiple times, 2 (`in` and `find()`) for each operator.

You could use `index()` instead of `find()` and just ignore the `ValueError` exception , e.g.:

```
def findNextOpr(txt):
    for o in '+-*/':
        try:
            return txt.index(o)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return -1
```

You can do this in a single (perhaps more readable) pass by `enumerate()`ing the `txt` and return if you find the character, e.g.:

```
def findNextOpr(txt):
    for i, c in enumerate(txt):
        if c in '+-*/':
            return i
    return -1
```

Note: if you wanted all of the operators you could change the `return` to `yield`, and then just iterate over the generator, e.g.:

```
def findNextOpr(txt):
    for i, c in enumerate(txt):
        if c in '+-*/':
            yield i

In []:
for op in findNextOpr('1+2-3+4'):
    print(op)

Out[]:
1
3
5
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the overhead of a Python `for` loop over `enumerate` compared to the C loop inside `index` wasn't more than 4x. It's still a cleaner and more readable solution, but I wouldn't pitch it as an optimization without actually testing that it's faster rather than slower in most cases…

Comment: Good point, I've removed the references to performance as it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your code a bit because you keep looking at the string a lot of times. `'+' in txt` actually searches through the string just like `txt.find('+')` does. So you can combine those easily to avoid having to search through it twice:

```
pos = txt.find('+')
if pos >= 0:
    return pos
```

But this still leaves you with the problem that this will return for the first operator you are looking for if that operator is contained anywhere within the string. So you don’t actually get the first position *any* of these operators is within the string.

So what you want to do is look for all operators separately, and then return the lowest non-negative number since that’s the first occurence of any of the operators within the string:

```
plusPos = txt.find('+')
minusPos = txt.find('-')
multPos = txt.find('*')
divPos = txt.find('/')

return min(pos for pos in (plusPos, minusPos, multPos, divPos) if pos >= 0)
```

Comment: Assume you meant `range(len(txt))`, though `enumerate()` is probably a more canonical approach.

Comment: @AChampion I did, thank you! And yeah, enumerate also works fine

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to go through several scenarios. The last one that mentions utilizing a loop accounts for the fact that there could be several instances of the operator correct? For example txt is "4 + 5 + 6 * 2". Here, there are 2 '+' operators. Since so long as '+' which is part of the mentioned string appears, the loop will continue.

Comment: As I mentioned in AChampion's question, the savings from looping 1 time instead of 4 may not actually outweigh the cost of looping in Python and repeatedly indexing vs. looping in C (or maybe even calling something like `memchr` that may even be more optimized than that…), especially in CPython. It's definitely better in the sense of cleaner and more readable, but it may not be faster, which your answer implies that it is.

Comment: @MJames28 Not sure I understand what you are saying. For a string `4 + 5 + 6 * 2`, the function would return `2` since at index 2, there is the first operator in the string. The loop would stop after that.

Comment: @abarnert That’s a very good point, and can be easily verified with a quick benchmark. I’ve removed the looping part and instead focused on getting the right answer with using just `str.find` calls. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be printing or returning error messages; you should be raising exceptions. `TypeError` and `ValueError` would be appropriate here. (A string that isn't long enough is the latter, not the former.)

Second, you can simply find the the positions of all the operators in the string using a list comprehension, exclude results of -1, and return the lowest of the positions using `min()`.

```
def findNextOpr(text, start=0):
    ops = "+-/*"
    assert isinstance(text, str), "text must be a string"
    # "text must not be empty" isn't strictly true: 
    # you'll get a perfectly sensible result for an empty string
    assert text, "text must not be empty"
    op_idxs = [pos for pos in (text.find(op, start) for op in ops) if pos > -1]
    return min(op_idxs) if op_idxs else -1
```

I've added a `start` argument that can be used to find the next operator: simply pass in the index of the last-found operator, plus 1.